# Android loader. Data is not dispatched after loader

Tags: android, loader

I am trying to put a loader in my android app and i am facing one the either problems.

1. The loader comes for 2 sec then goes away
2. The loader keeps on loading but the data is not dispatched which should come after loading completes.
3. The loader does not comes at all and the data is dispatched.

I HAVE TRIED A LOT OF CODES FROM STACKOVERFLOW BUT DID NOT SUCCEEDED. HENCE FINALLY POSTED THE PROBLEM IN WORDS TO BETTER UNDERSTAND.
KINDLY HELP

Comment: Where is your code Sir?

Comment: i used multiple codes but they didn't worked. that is the reason i did not specified any of the code. You please give me the code that will definately work